# What is and why NodeSource, in layman's terms?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

Recently I did some research on how to host a MEAN stack web app on AWS.

One of the tutorials I followed is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z87H9_1cAHo and the tutor adds a NodeJS PPA from **nodesource.com**.

Can someone please tell me whether using NodeSource was purely arbitrary, or is "NodeSource" a must or a best practice when it comes to hosting a MEAN stack web app on AWS?

I searched online on what is NodeSource and why it is necessary, but didn't find anything (or anything that I understand).

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install Node.js from *somewhere* (at least if you are starting with a freshly installed OS).

The person who wrote that guide had already picked an operating system and a distribution of that operating system.

That site happens to provide a version of Node.js that compatible with that distribution's package manager.

(Presumably a newer version of Node.js then the official PPA sources for that distro).

It isn't a requirement or a best practise.